# When used as particles, do 의 and 에 sound the same?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

I've recently begun learning Korean and I just learned that 의 is often pronounced like 에, hence why 저의 becomes 제.

If this is the case, how can I tell the difference between 의 and 에 in speech?

Comment: related (or possible duplicate): https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/353/pronunciation-of-%EC%9D%98?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

They are often pronounced the same. When this is the case, then rather like with English homophones like for/four or hear/here, you just have to tell from the context.

Normally, 의 will link to another *noun* that comes after:

> 한국의 **수도**는 서울이다 - Korea's capital is Seoul.

에 will usually link to a *verb* that comes after:

> 어디에 **가요**? - Where are you going?

Comment: Small correction: the last sentence should be "나는 언니**에게** 빵을 줬다."  People and animals take "-에게" when they receive something; (I think) everything else uses "-에".

Comment: @jick I thought I'd heard Koreans say person+에 - do you think that's actually really 'unnatural', or could it be just 'casual'?

Comment: @topomorto We use -에 for non-human beings(무정물), such as companies. We use -에게 only for humans or "conscious beings(유정물)". Koreans sometimes (wrongly) use -에게 in place of -에, but they almost never use -에 in place of -에게.

ex) 도서관**에** 책을 반납했다, 친구**에게** 모르는 문제를 물어보았다.

Comment: @topomorto I don't know if younger generations recently developed a new pattern (happens all the time), but to my (~40-year-old) ears, "언니에" does not sound right. (As Jihyung said, *organizations* get "-에", so you will have 학교에, 정부에, 경찰서에, 담당 부서에, 가정에, etc., but 사람들에게, 가족/식구에게, 친구들에게, etc.)